# Using Cocoa, NSPrintOperation, How Do I correctly Create a PDF file from text in an NSView?

Tags: cocoa, pdf-generation, nsview, nsprintoperation

Using NSPrintOperation, How Do I correctly Create a PDF file from text in an NSView?

---

*
* NOTICE I FOUND A WORKAROUND, WHICH IS SHOWN AT THE BOTTOM
*

---

What I have done: 
1. Put text into an NSTextView.

```
- (NSTextView *)printableViewWithRecipe:(Recipe *)recipe
{

[_printView setString:@""];
[_printView setTextColor:[NSColor textColor]];
[_printView setFont:[NSFont userFontOfSize:0]];
NSDictionary    *titleAttr;
_printView = [[NSTextView alloc] initWithFrame:[[self printInfo] imageablePageBounds]];
[_printView setVerticallyResizable:YES];
[_printView setHorizontallyResizable:NO];

// Begin to ADD THE TEXT
[[_printView textStorage] beginEditing];

// Set the attributes for the title
[[_printView textStorage] beginEditing];
titleAttr =
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[(AppDelegate*)[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate] tableFont] forKey:NSFontAttributeName];

// Add the title
[
 [_printView textStorage] appendAttributedString:
 [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[recipe name]  attributes:titleAttr ]
];

// Create a couple returns between the title and the body
[[_printView textStorage] appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"\n\n"]];

// Add the body text
if([[recipe ingredients] length] )
    [[_printView textStorage] appendAttributedString: [ [NSAttributedString alloc]
                                                      initWithString:[recipe ingredients] attributes:titleAttr]];
// Create a couple returns between the ingredients and the directions
[[_printView textStorage] appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"\n\n"]];
if([[recipe directions] length] )
    [[_printView textStorage] appendAttributedString: [ [NSAttributedString alloc]
                                                      initWithString:[recipe directions] attributes:titleAttr]];
// Create a couple returns between the directions and the comments
[[_printView textStorage] appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"\n\n"]];
if([[recipe comments] length] )
    [[_printView textStorage] appendAttributedString: [ [NSAttributedString alloc]
                                                      initWithString:[recipe comments] attributes:titleAttr]];
// Center the title
[_printView setAlignment:NSCenterTextAlignment range:NSMakeRange(0, [[recipe name] length])];

[[_printView textStorage] endEditing];

return _printView;

} // end printableViewForRecipe
```

2.Try to Create a PDF file from the TextView's Text using the method below:

```
- (PDFDocument *)exportPDFfromView:(NSTextView*)textView  fileNumber:(NSUInteger)fileNumber
{ 
    NSPrintInfo *printInfo;
    NSPrintInfo *sharedInfo;
    NSPrintOperation *printOp;
    NSMutableDictionary *printInfoDict;
    NSMutableDictionary *sharedDict;
    sharedInfo = [NSPrintInfo sharedPrintInfo];
    sharedDict = [sharedInfo dictionary];
    printInfoDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary: sharedDict];
    [printInfoDict setObject:NSPrintSaveJob forKey:NSPrintJobDisposition];
    NSString *tempFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_file_%lu.pdf", [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] globallyUniqueString], fileNumber];
    NSURL *poTempfileURL = [_tempDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:tempFileName];
    [printInfoDict setObject:poTempfileURL forKey:NSPrintJobSavingURL];
    printInfo = [[NSPrintInfo alloc] initWithDictionary:printInfoDict];//1
    [printInfo setHorizontalPagination: NSAutoPagination];//2
    [printInfo setVerticalPagination: NSAutoPagination];//3
    [printInfo setVerticallyCentered:NO];//4

    printOp = [NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView:textView printInfo:printInfo];//5
    [printOp setShowsPrintPanel:NO];
    [printOp setShowsProgressPanel:NO];//6
    DLog(@"poTempfileURL=%@",poTempfileURL);

    BOOL didRunOK = [printOp runOperation];//7
    BOOL exists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[poTempfileURL path]];
    DLog(@"poTempfileURL=%@",poTempfileURL);
    DLog(@"didRunOK=%lu\nfileExists=%lu",didRunOK,exists);
    PDFDocument *doc = [[PDFDocument alloc] initWithURL:poTempfileURL];

    return doc;
}
```

3. Run the following code :

   ```
   [self tempDirectoryURL];// invoke getter
   NSLog(@"_tempDirectoryURL=%@",_tempDirectoryURL);

   _tempDirectoryURL=file:///var/folders/8p/c2x7m74j1wzdf92jy770zx500000gn/T/com.DrummingGrouse.HungryMe/
   ```

The Getter follows:

```
- (NSURL *)tempDirectoryURL { //getter
    NSURL *tempURL;
    if(!_tempDirectoryURL){
        tempURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] globallyUniqueString]] isDirectory:YES];
        _tempDirectoryURL = tempURL;
    }
    return _tempDirectoryURL;
}
```

4. After running this code:

   BOOL didRunOK = [printOp runOperation];//7

   BOOL exists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[poTempfileURL path]];
    DLog(@"didRunOK=%lu\nfileExists=%lu",didRunOK,exists);
    DLog(@"poTempfileURL=%@",poTempfileURL);

I expect a PDF to be created at: poTempfileURL where it value is:
     poTempfileURL=file:///var/folders/8p/c2x7m74j1wzdf92jy770zx500000gn/T/com.DrummingGrouse.HungryMe/884B9B4C-907B-489E-869B-B5EFE7A11B47-1821-000016435C134E56/7A196040-0D81-496D-B9F3-BF0B855F6BBC-1821-0000164A9446040F_file_0.pdf

console shows:

```
 didRunOK=1
 fileExists=1
```

5. When the following line of code runs:

   BOOL didRunOK = [printOp runOperation];//7

The contents of printInfo for the printOp are:

```
{
    NSBottomMargin = 90;
    NSCopies = 1;
    NSDestinationFormat = "application/pdf";
    NSDetailedErrorReporting = 0;
    NSFaxNumber = "";
    NSFirstPage = 1;
    NSHorizonalPagination = 0;
    NSHorizontallyCentered = 0;
    NSJobDisposition = NSPrintSaveJob;
    NSJobSavingFileNameExtensionHidden = 0;
    NSJobSavingURL = "file:///var/folders/8p/c2x7m74j1wzdf92jy770zx500000gn/T/com.DrummingGrouse.HungryMe/2687B4CD-6ABF-4826-B8F8-3D536FFACA66-1362-00001DEFA0B13D70/1F0483BF-00B4-4F65-A3C7-C4824F53C03E-1362-00001DF033AAD968_file_0.pdf";
    NSLastPage = 2147483647;
    NSLeftMargin = 72;
    NSMustCollate = 1;
    NSOrientation = 0;
    NSPagesAcross = 1;
    NSPagesDown = 1;
    NSPaperName = "na-letter";
    NSPaperSize = "NSSize: {612, 792}";
    NSPrintAllPages = 1;
    NSPrintProtected = 0;
    NSPrintSelectionOnly = 0;
    NSPrintTime = "0000-12-30 00:00:00 +0000";
    NSPrinter = "{\n    \"Device Description\" =     {\n        NSDeviceIsPrinter = YES;\n    };\n    \"Language Level\" = 3;\n    Name = \"HP DESKJET 840C @ Mark\\U2019s Mac Pro\";\n    Type = \"Generic PCL Laser Printer\";\n}";
    NSPrinterName = "HP DESKJET 840C @ Mark\U2019s Mac Pro";
    NSRightMargin = 72;
    NSSavePath = "/var/folders/8p/c2x7m74j1wzdf92jy770zx500000gn/T/com.DrummingGrouse.HungryMe/2687B4CD-6ABF-4826-B8F8-3D536FFACA66-1362-00001DEFA0B13D70/1F0483BF-00B4-4F65-A3C7-C4824F53C03E-1362-00001DF033AAD968_file_0.pdf";
    NSScalingFactor = 1;
    NSTopMargin = 90;
    NSVerticalPagination = 0;
    NSVerticallyCentered = 0;
}
```

In Xcode : po [[textView textStorage] string] produces the text below labeled :

```
 /// BEGIN NSTextView TEXT ///
```

In Finder when I open the file located at poTempFileURL,
   in Preview, the file has four pages (it should have only one page), 
   and appears to be an empty PDF file in Preview.

When I open this same "PDF" file in TextEdit, the file contains the 
   content below which is labelled :  /// BEGIN TEXT PDF Tempfile ///

What do I need to do to produce a "proper" PDF file? I can not get a PDF that I can open and read in Preview.

po [doc pageCount] shows "4"

/// BEGIN NSTextView TEXT ///  - po [[textView textStorage] string]

```
French Toast

[French Toast]
preptime 0:03 cooktime 0:08 serves:1-2

egg   1     
milk   3/4  cup 
ground cinnamon   1/8  tsp  (optional)
best bread   2  slices  
butter   4  tsp (two per side)
maple syrup     (to taste)


[French Toast]

1. Add egg to a bowl and beat with a fork. 

2. Add milk and cinnamon to egg and beat briefly.

3. Heat heavy skillet to medium high. Add 2 tsp butter. 

4. Dip bread slice halves in batter and brown in skillet. Flip and add additional butter. Brown and serve with syrup.

Serve with pork sausage, chorizo or bacon.
```

/// END  NSTextView TEXT ///

/// BEGIN TEXT PDF Tempfile ///

```
%PDF-1.3
%ƒÂÚÂÎßÛ†–ƒ∆
4 0 obj
<< /Length 5 0 R /Filter /FlateDecode >>
stream
x+T�Á�„
endstream
endobj
5 0 obj
11
endobj
2 0 obj
<< /Type /Page /Parent 3 0 R /Resources 6 0 R /Contents 4 0 R /MediaBox [0 0 612 792]
>>
endobj
6 0 obj
<< /ProcSet [ /PDF ] >>
endobj
8 0 obj
<< /Length 9 0 R /Filter /FlateDecode >>
stream
x+T�Á�„
endstream
endobj
9 0 obj
11
endobj
7 0 obj
<< /Type /Page /Parent 3 0 R /Resources 10 0 R /Contents 8 0 R /MediaBox [0 0 612 792]
>>
endobj
10 0 obj
<< /ProcSet [ /PDF ] >>
endobj
12 0 obj
<< /Length 13 0 R /Filter /FlateDecode >>
stream
x+T�Á�„
endstream
endobj
13 0 obj
11
endobj
11 0 obj
<< /Type /Page /Parent 3 0 R /Resources 14 0 R /Contents 12 0 R /MediaBox
[0 0 612 792] >>
endobj
14 0 obj
<< /ProcSet [ /PDF ] >>
endobj
16 0 obj
<< /Length 17 0 R /Filter /FlateDecode >>
stream
x+T�Á�„
endstream
endobj
17 0 obj
11
endobj
15 0 obj
<< /Type /Page /Parent 3 0 R /Resources 18 0 R /Contents 16 0 R /MediaBox
[0 0 612 792] >>
endobj
18 0 obj
<< /ProcSet [ /PDF ] >>
endobj
3 0 obj
<< /Type /Pages /MediaBox [0 0 612 792] /Count 4 /Kids [ 2 0 R 7 0 R 11 0 R
15 0 R ] >>
endobj
19 0 obj
<< /Type /Catalog /Pages 3 0 R >>
endobj
20 0 obj
(Untitled)
endobj
21 0 obj
(Mac OS X 10.10.3 Quartz PDFContext)
endobj
22 0 obj
(HungryMe)
endobj
23 0 obj
(D:20150513191029Z00'00')
endobj
24 0 obj
()
endobj
25 0 obj
[ ]
endobj
1 0 obj
<< /Title 20 0 R /Producer 21 0 R /Creator 22 0 R /CreationDate 23 0 R /ModDate
23 0 R /Keywords 24 0 R /AAPL:Keywords 25 0 R >>
endobj
xref
0 26
0000000000 65535 f 
0000001363 00000 n 
0000000125 00000 n 
0000001022 00000 n 
0000000022 00000 n 
0000000107 00000 n 
0000000229 00000 n 
0000000371 00000 n 
0000000268 00000 n 
0000000353 00000 n 
0000000476 00000 n 
0000000622 00000 n 
0000000516 00000 n 
0000000603 00000 n 
0000000729 00000 n 
0000000875 00000 n 
0000000769 00000 n 
0000000856 00000 n 
0000000982 00000 n 
0000001125 00000 n 
0000001175 00000 n 
0000001202 00000 n 
0000001255 00000 n 
0000001282 00000 n 
0000001324 00000 n 
0000001343 00000 n 
trailer
<< /Size 26 /Root 19 0 R /Info 1 0 R /ID [ <1abd1092f1d909274c086bf0f90d6200>
<1abd1092f1d909274c086bf0f90d6200> ] >>
startxref
1507
%%EOF
```

/// END  TEXT PDF Tempfile

If I redo the method exportPDFfromView: fileNumber: this way,

```
- (PDFDocument *)exportPDFfromView:(NSTextView*)textView  fileNumber:(NSUInteger)fileNumber
{
    NSString *tempFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_file_%lu.pdf", [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] globallyUniqueString], fileNumber];
    NSURL *poTempfileURL = [_tempDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:tempFileName];
    DLog(@"poTempfileURL=%@",poTempfileURL);

    NSRect r = [textView bounds];
    NSData *data = [textView dataWithPDFInsideRect:r];
    [data writeToFile:poTempfileURL.path atomically:YES];
    PDFDocument *doc2 = [[PDFDocument alloc] initWithURL:poTempfileURL];
    DLog(@"doc2.pageCount=%lu",doc2.pageCount);

    ...

    return doc2;
}
```

when I view the resultant PDF file at URL poTempfileURL, it has one page, which is correct. But again the PDF 
shows no text in Preview. If I view this "PDF" with TextEdit, the contents are below.

```
%PDF-1.3
%ƒÂÚÂÎßÛ†–ƒ∆
4 0 obj
<< /Length 5 0 R /Filter /FlateDecode >>
stream
x+TÁ„
endstream
endobj
5 0 obj
11
endobj
2 0 obj
<< /Type /Page /Parent 3 0 R /Resources 6 0 R /Contents 4 0 R /MediaBox [0 0 576 734]
>>
endobj
6 0 obj
<< /ProcSet [ /PDF ] >>
endobj
3 0 obj
<< /Type /Pages /MediaBox [0 0 576 734] /Count 1 /Kids [ 2 0 R ] >>
endobj
7 0 obj
<< /Type /Catalog /Pages 3 0 R >>
endobj
8 0 obj
(Mac OS X 10.10.3 Quartz PDFContext)
endobj
9 0 obj
(D:20150517134359Z00'00')
endobj
1 0 obj
<< /Producer 8 0 R /CreationDate 9 0 R /ModDate 9 0 R >>
endobj
xref
0 10
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000493 00000 n 
0000000125 00000 n 
0000000268 00000 n 
0000000022 00000 n 
0000000107 00000 n 
0000000229 00000 n 
0000000351 00000 n 
0000000400 00000 n 
0000000452 00000 n 
trailer
<< /Size 10 /Root 7 0 R /Info 1 0 R /ID [ <d86abf98c49359ba2092ad602722f659>
<d86abf98c49359ba2092ad602722f659> ] >>
startxref
565
%%EOF
```

! ! ! !

I have found a workaround that will get me where I want to go. This still does not explain to me why all my seemingly endless attempts to use

```
    + (NSPrintOperation *)printOperationWithView:(NSView *)aView
                               printInfo:(NSPrintInfo *)aPrintInfo
```

fail.

The workaround produces multipage PDF files that can be viewed in Preview.

I do hope this is useful to others.

```
- (void)testQuartz:(NSData *)pdfDocumentData savePath:(NSString*)savePath
{
   //Create the pdf document reference
   CGDataProviderRef dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((CFDataRef)pdfDocumentData);
   CGPDFDocumentRef document = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider(dataProvider);

   //Create the pdf context
   CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(document, 1); //Pages are numbered starting at 1
   CGRect pageRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page, kCGPDFMediaBox);
   CFMutableDataRef mutableData = CFDataCreateMutable(NULL, 0);

   //NSLog(@"w:%2.2f, h:%2.2f",pageRect.size.width, pageRect.size.height);
   CGDataConsumerRef dataConsumer = CGDataConsumerCreateWithCFData(mutableData);
   CGContextRef pdfContext = CGPDFContextCreate(dataConsumer, &pageRect, NULL);


   if (CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(document) > 0)
   {
      //Draw the page onto the new context
      //page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(document, 1); //Pages are numbered starting at 1

      CGPDFContextBeginPage(pdfContext, NULL);
      CGContextDrawPDFPage(pdfContext, page);
      CGPDFContextEndPage(pdfContext);
   }
   else
   {
      NSLog(@"Failed to create the document");
   }

   CGContextRelease(pdfContext); //Release before writing data to disk.

   //Write to disk
   [(__bridge NSData *)mutableData writeToFile:savePath atomically:YES];

   //Clean up
   CGDataProviderRelease(dataProvider); //Release the data provider
   CGDataConsumerRelease(dataConsumer);
   CGPDFDocumentRelease(document);
   CFRelease(mutableData);
}


- (PDFDocument *)exportPDFfromView:(NSTextView*)textView  fileNumber:(NSUInteger)fileNumber
{
    NSString *tempFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_file_%lu.pdf", [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] globallyUniqueString], fileNumber];
    NSURL *poTempfileURL = [_tempDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:tempFileName];
    DLog(@"poTempfileURL=%@",poTempfileURL);

    NSRect r = [textView bounds];
    NSData *data = [textView dataWithPDFInsideRect:r];

   [ self testQuartz:(NSData *)data savePath:poTempfileURL.path ];

    ...

    return aDoc;
}
```

If you are like me and want to publish a single PDF, with say essays, all beginning at the top of a page in the single PDF, you will probably want something like the following to take pages out of temporary input documents and move them all into the single output PDF.

```
    NSUInteger pageCountDocZero = [[inputDocuments objectAtIndex:0] pageCount];
    NSUInteger pageIndex = pageCountDocZero;
    for (PDFDocument *document in inputDocuments) {
        for (NSUInteger j = 0; j < [document pageCount]; j++) {
            PDFPage *page = [document pageAtIndex:j];
            DLog(@"Inserting pageIndex:%lu i.e inputPage:%lu of %lu",pageIndex,j+1,[document pageCount]);
            [outputDocument insertPage:page atIndex:pageIndex++];
        }
    }
```

Comment: well done, i found this very helpful

Comment: Please place the answer to your own question in a separate answer.